# B1 has voting limited by "time since 1st June". Can they abuse it using eosio.token transfer?

Tags: smart-contract, voting, token-distribution

Going through [eosio.system contract](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.system), I've noticed [following lines](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L203), that limit Block.one EOSIO voting power by time:

```
void validate_b1_vesting( int64_t stake ) {
  const int64_t base_time = 1527811200; /// 2018-06-01
  const int64_t max_claimable = 100'000'000'0000ll;
  const int64_t claimable = int64_t(max_claimable * double(now()-base_time) / (10*seconds_per_year) );

  eosio_assert( max_claimable - claimable <= stake, "b1 can only claim their tokens over 10 years" );
}
```

This is used in [system_contract::changebw](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/delegate_bandwidth.cpp#L373) and makes restriction that B1 can't vote with full stake of 100M tokens right now.

I can't see any code that prohibits B1 from transferring their tokens to someone else, and voting from there. Can they abuse limited voting using `eosio.token transfer` action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael Yeates answered this question in one of community Telegrams, this is my rephrase:

This `validate_b1_vesting` check is used in `system_contract::changebw()` and will cause `eosio_assert` when B1 tries to undelegate more tokens than available by current point of time. Since they cannot undelegate, they cannot transfer it further. Blockchain is secure.